# How to count mean of a column 2 if column 1 has a specific value? R

Tags: r, mean

How can I count the mean of Column 2 if Column 1 has a value of "UK"?

```
Column1  | Column2
-------------------
USA      | 4.5
UK       | 4.3
UK       | 2.4
UK       | 1.3
GERMANY  | 4.4
FRANCE   | 2.3
```

So I want to get mean of Columns 2 for UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the 'Column2' based on the 'Column1' value o 'UK' and get the `mean`

```
with(df1, mean(Column2[Column1 == 'UK']))
```

---

Or if we need to get the `mean` of 'Column2' for all unique elements of 'Column1'

```
aggregate(Column2 ~ Column1, df1, mean)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Column1) %>%
  summarise(Column2 = mean(Column2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks mate! The second one did exactly what I intended.